# Python Higher Order Function: New way to find Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: python, fibonacci, higher-order-functions

I am given a question to write a higher order function to find fibonacci numbers.
First, I am defined the `combine` function below:

```
def combine(f, op ,n):
    result = f(0)
    for i in range(n):
        result = op(result, f(i))
return result
```

For example, `new_fib(10) = 55`

The function I'm supposed to define is thus to find the nth fibonacci number:

```
def new_fib(n):
    def f(x):
        ...
    def op(x, y):
        ...
    return combine(f, op, n+1)
```

The idea I have to solve this question is simply to chuck the fibonacci sequence into the `f(x)` function, but I've been facing a lot of problems. Here's what I have now:

```
def new_fib(n):
    def op(x,y):
        return x+y
    def f(x):
        a,b = 0, 1
        fibs = ()
        for i in range(n+1):
            a, b = b, a+b
            fibs += (a,)
        return fibs[x]
    return combine(f, op, n+1)
```

But that's wrong because it accumulates too fast. I can picture why in my head, but cannot figure a way out to get around it. Does anyone have any advice? It would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The operation should just be `a, b => b, a+b`, and you iterate it.

Code could be:

```
def new_fib(n):
    def op(a, b):
        return b, a+b
    def combine(initial, op, n):
        a, b = initial
        for i in range(n):
            a, b = op(a, b)
        return b
    if n == 0:                # special processing for 0 and 1
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return combine((0,1), op, n - 1)
```

It correctly gives `55` for `new_fib(10)`

Answer (score -1):

```
def combine(f, op ,n):
    result = f(0)
    for i in range(n):
        result = op(result, f(i))
    return result

def new_fib(n):
    def f(x):
        a,b = 0,1
        if x==0:
            return 0
        elif x==1:
            return 1
        else:
            for i in range(x-2):
                a,b = b,a+b
            return a

    def op(x, y):
        return x+y

    return combine(f, op, n+1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post. Also see [the help page on formatting](/help/formatting) on how to use code formatting on your posts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).